# CSS Fixed position on bottom within a wrapper

Tags: html, css, css-position

I'm trying to get my footer displayed at the bottom of the page. Usually it's just position: fixed and bottom: 0. However I want my footer positioned inside a container (section element), so when the size of my sidebar at the left changes, I want my footer be also moved to the right or left.

I thought I could get use of position: sticky instead of width, but when there's not enough content inside of section element, it is displayed at the bottom of the section, but not at the bottom of the page.
Is there a pure CSS solution for this or have I add some javascript?

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
.page-body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 7rem calc(100vw - 7rem);
}
.sidebar {
  background-color: yellow;
}
section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
  background-color: green;
}
.content {
  padding-top: 400px;
}
footer {
  position: -webkit-sticky;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 10px;
  background-color: blue;
  z-index: 999;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="page-body">
      <div class="sidebar">
      </div>
      <section>
        <div>
          <div class="content">
            Content
          </div>
        </div>
        <footer>
          Footer
        </footer>
      </section>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the padding-top on the .content class add height 100vh to it and remove the bottom:10px on footer can solve your problem

```
.content {
  height:100vh;
 }
```